# Why does Ctrl+Tab behave differently in different programs?

Tags: tabs, keyboard-shortcuts

In some programs such as IDEs/code editors, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through tabs in the most recent order (and in Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through apps in the most recent order), whereas in web browsers and Photoshop, it cycles through tabs in the order they appear in the tabs bar. Why the disparity in such a commonly used shortcut?

Personally, I greatly prefer the first method, as it makes switching between any two tabs so much quicker (and is in line with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Internet Explorer nailed it with an option for both methods, alas Edge only does the latter method. Why don't any other programs offer the choice?

Comment: As worded, there is no answer to this question that is not pure opinion and speculation. Different apps behave differently because they were coded to behave that way. Without asking the companies themselves we can't answer why they did it one way over the other, or why the don't offer a choice.

Comment: It's sounds like Why Window's Minimize-Maximize-Close are on right, and Apple has it on left?

Comment: @divy3993 Not really because in that case there isn't a fundamental inconsistency in UI behaviour between the two

Comment: Yes that's true, i agree with you. Also i noticed this functionality is mostly in OS software's/tools and Software's that are somewhat technical.

Answer (score 1):

You can make some assumptions about the usage of different apps.

With code (and to some extent apps), it is common to open/close many and wish to toggle between the most recent two. By 'open many' I mean to an extent that user reordering of the tabs will only hold for a short period, by that involving not-the-greatest payoff for the effort.

I don't think you can make such assumption about web browsing or photoshop documents (although I'm sure you'll find some cases).